# Sails.js don't run with sails lift - Ubuntu

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, sails.js

I created an issue on the official github:
https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/921

The problem is:

Node.js works.

Sails.js was installed with -g.

When I write `node app.js` my application start well on the port 80 but sails is not started. (Obviously)

But Sails.js is not responding, for example:

```
sails lift | sails | sails-v
```

Theses commands line don't give me any response, I don't know why. I'm using *Ubuntu 13.04.* Nothing appends when I write them on the shell.

Do you have any idea how fix this?
Thank you.
I will try on another virtual machine with *Ubuntu 12.04*. Maybe it's because of this :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution found here:

https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/921#issuecomment-25048742

It was because of this:

```
Maybe try changing the first line of /usr/bin/sails to #!/usr/bin/env nodejs?
```

In the file

```
/usr/bin/sails
```